# setlocale having no effect in PHP

Tags: php, locale

I have the following snippet of code:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "de");
print(strftime("%A %e %B %Y", time()));
```

and it's printing

> Tuesday 4 May 2010

instead of

> Dienstag 4. Mai 2010

Any ideas why? How to fix?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do you have the `de` locale available; what does `setlocale` return for you? See: [return values for setlocale()](http://php.net/setlocale).

Also, check the list of available locales (e.g. `locale -a` or whatever is suitable for your OS) to see if `de` is among them.  Likely alternatives include `de_DE` or `de_DE.utf8` to name a few.

In Debian, to generate a new locale, run this command:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

and pick the ones you want.

Answer (score 5):

Setting the locale will have no effect if the locale is not installed on your system.

Answer (score 5):

I am using Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi, had the same issue trying to use Portuguese local for date:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "C");
echo strftime("%A");
echo setlocale(LC_TIME, "pt_PT");
echo strftime(" in Portuguese %A");
```

Then checked with command ***local -a***, pt_PT was not on the list, so I added it ***sudo /usr/share/locales/install-language-pack pt_PT*** and run ***local -a*** again: there it was **pt_PT.utf8**.
After this, result still the same: output expected for pt_PT still in English.
Here is the slight difference that made things work to me:

```
···
echo setlocale(LC_TIME, "pt_PT.utf8");
···
```

So, I had to turn **pt_PT** into **pt_PT.utf8**

Comment: This is what worked for me. What I did though is to install the whole language pack, not specifying one in particular:

`/usr/share/locales/install-language-pack es`

Comment: There is a typo: "setlocale" instead of "etlocale" in the first line of the example code. Could not edit it, sorry!

Answer (score 4):

For me the following did the trick:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "");
```

In combination with:

```
echo strftime("%d. %B %Y");
```

That is how I got the current date in German format. Hope that can help.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `LC_ALL` to "de_DE". On my system it wouldn't work until I did that.

```
$ LC_ALL=de date
Tue May  4 07:40:13 CDT 2010
$ LC_ALL=de_DE date
Di 4. Mai 07:39:27 CDT 2010
```

Answer (score 2):

```
locale -a
locale-gen nb_NO.UTF-8
locale-gen nb_NO
update-locale
locale -a
restart php5-fpm
```

Comment: Please try to provide some explanation of what a solution you're posting does.

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that you will probably need to restart httpd and php-fpm services after generating new locales in Linux.

Without restart php (7.2) couldn't find them, even when listed in locale -a.

Hope it will save someone some time :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you don't have the locale installed so if you are on ubuntu you can check the list with "locale -a" without the cuotes, and check the available languajes in the file /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED and them generated the locale required with "locale-gen de_DE"

hope this work for you.