# Php mysql date in table

Tags: php

I have a date field in my table material

- id: int;
- dat_operation : date;
- name : varchar(255);

I would like to know how to translate date format in French
I tried with:

```
<?php  echo date("F j Y",strtotime($var['date_operation']));?>
```

But i have this result

```
June 14 2016
```

Comment: Could you define what the desired output is? (Not everybody knows _all_ the different date-formats from around the world...)

Comment: Or do you want "June" beeing translated to french?

Comment: @Jeff yes,  i want to translate June in french

Comment: those answers might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328036/php-date-in-foreign-languages-e-g-mar-25-ao%C3%BB-09

Comment: You can use setlocale() to translate the language of the date: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765247/setlocale-having-no-effect-in-php

Comment: and here's the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll have to set the "locale information", to specify which language you want to use. Keep in mind, that even though you set that language, it needs to be installed on the server you're running on. It most likely is, but you'll notice if the `setlocale` has no effect (default is English).

The second thing you'll need to know, is that `date()` isn't affected by this, you'll have to use [`strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) instead, which has a slightly different formatting, which you'll find on the documentation.

An example of using French dates with these two functions:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR'); 
echo strftime("%B %e %Y", strtotime($var['date_operation']));
```

Reference and documentation:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Answer (score 1):

The modern and rock-solid approach is the [intl (from "Internationalization") extension](http://php.net/intl), which offers e.g. the [`IntlDateFormatter` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php):

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-06-14');
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter('fr_FR', IntlDateFormatter::LONG, IntlDateFormatter::NONE, 'Europe/Paris', IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN);
var_dump($fmt->format($date));
```

```
string(12) "14 juin 2016"
```

If you think it's overkill for your project, you can use the legacy [strftime()](http://php.net/strftime) function but you need to change current locale:

```
$date = strtotime('2016-06-14');
var_dump(setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR', 'fr')); // Need to try values until you get true
var_dump(strftime('%B %e %Y', $date));
```

You need to have French locale data installed. In my experience, this works better on Unix-like systems than on Windows.